# Rendering controller/action within a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a way in Ruby on Rails to render a completely different controller's action within other views.

For example I am writing a band website that displays their albums.  So I have /albums/list that shows a list of all of their albums with other stuff around the page as the layout.  Now what I am looking to do is also render /news/list in every page as part of the layout as well so that every page you go to you can see it.

I cannot find a way to call the news controller list action and display it in the list view using partial views.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sound like you might want to break that action into a partial and render that?

Comment: I have tried turning it into a partial like /news/_list.  However, it still requires that I either pass in the news collection or query the news collection within the Album controller, or application level.  I can't figure out a way to render a partial and have it flow through NewsController._list to the list view.

Comment: Sounds you want to keep it pretty strict and restful?  You could request json from the NewsController.

Comment: Other than that it seems the most logical way would be to create a shared partial and set up the @news collection

Comment: Yes, trying to follow a strict design as much as possible.  I already have made it so the application controller queries the news since I need it everywhere.  Was just hoping for a better option.  I wonder if someday Rails will support sub views as completely separate things instead of just one request type thing.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render

render() method give you ability to render specific file, placed in any directory :)

also read this article - http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2 especially about "Custom partial paths".

Comment: The problem here is that the NewsController doesn't get invoked.  The render function only goes right to the view file.  So in this case I would have to query the news in every page, or have a before filter at the application level, so that the news view can be displayed since it relies on @news being initialized.